# setup youtube-dl destination to ~/Downloads

Tags: macos, command-line, youtube

How do I setup [`youtube-dl`](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) to default download to ~/Downloads instead of the home folder?

Comment: This question is not specific to OS X. youtube-dl is pretty much cross-platform application. I think it must be moved to Superuser.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## `youtube-dl` Config File

To set a default download location, create a `youtube-dl` [configuration file](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#configuration) at:

```
~/.config/youtube-dl/config
```

Within this file enter the line:

```
-o ~/Downloads/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s
```

You can create this file using the following two commands:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/youtube-dl/
echo "-o ~/Downloads/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s" > ~/.config/youtube-dl/config
```

The first command `mkdir`, creates the folders leading to the configuration file. The second command `echo` writes the output option into the file.

Options set within your configuration file are applied to every call to `youtube-dl`. Use the `--ignore-config` option to disable reading of the configuration file.

Comment: I like grahams solution better than mine for use with youtube-dl. My version works for every application, though.

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution. But now I’m getting mkv instead of mp4 files.

Comment: Add the following line to your config file to either request mp4 files or have youtube-dl convert after downloading to mp4: `--format mp4`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't download to your home, but to the current working directory. Change it before you want to download. If you're using `bash`, you might want to create a function in your `.bashrc` like this:

```
function youtube-dl ()
{
    cd ~/Downloads/ && {
        `which youtube-dl` "$@"
        cd - > /dev/null
    }
}
```

This changes the working directory to the Downloads folder in your home, runs the original `youtube-dl` with the command line arguments you passed to the function and then changes the directory back.

You also may want to have a look at this: [How do I run a program with a different working directory from current, from Linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-lin) as this also applies to OS X.

Comment: Did you test whether the ``which youtube-dl`` part works? Doesn't this expand to the function once it (the function) is defined?

Comment: No. Functions are not in the scope of `which`. Which searches in PATH. I also tested the script a few times ;)

Comment: To expand functions by name, use `typedef -F` or `-f`

Comment: Hmm, `which` is aliased to `type -p` here which returns nothing if `type -t` wouldn't return `file` (which is doesn't as it is a function now). Great if it works in your case, strange nevertheless.

Comment: `which`s manpage states the following: "locate a program file in the user's path". `which which` also returns an executable under PATH. `alias which` returns nothing for me, neither on the old-age bash OS X shipped version nor on a current one. 

Besides, as `youtube-dl` can take more than one argument, I intentionally didn't add quotation marks around `$@`.

Comment: '$@' *must* have quotation marks to properly expand in all cases, check Parameters/Special parameters in `man bash` for details (`When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter  expands  to  a  separate
              word.   That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ...`) .

Comment: If `\`which youtube-dl\`` is intended to avoid the function calling itself, a better (and portable!) approach is to use [`command youtube-dl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html).

Comment: What system lacks which?

Comment: Your approach will fail if `youtube-dl` is located at a path that contains spaces. It's fixable, but why not just use the standard commands the way they're supposed to be used?

Comment: the standard Commands (```...-o ~/Downloads/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s```) failed to work for me. I'm Using Mac OS X 10.12. This did the trick, I don't know why..

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of setting a default folder. Instead, you have to append the option `-o` every time.

```
 -o ~/Downloads/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s
```

- `%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s` is the default filename format for every download.