# Typing into Terminal works, AppleScript partially works

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line

**What I am trying to achieve:**

1. Click a YouTube link in an app
2. This URL is used by my `youtube-dl` script to download the video
3. `youtube-dl` is configured to download the highest quality video and audio, then use ffmpeg to combine them into one file

**What I have so far:**

I use [Finicky](https://github.com/johnste/finicky) as my default browser. This gives me control over what browsers open certain links based on rules I write for it. The long and short of the tool is that it detects YouTube links, converts them from their usual form (e.g. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxXxXxXXX_X`) to the shortened, share-friendly form (e.g. `https://youtu.be/XxXxXxXXX_X`), then sends this to an AppleScript.

The AppleScript is saved as an app and is below.

```
#!/bin/zsh
on open location input
    do shell script "youtube-dl  " & input
end open location
```

This runs the shell script `youtube-dl https://youtu.be/XxXxXxXXX_X`. When I type this exact command into Terminal everything works perfectly: `youtube-dl` does it's thing, including doing something with ffmpeg to combine the downloaded files. However, when this AppleScript runs it's like ffmpeg isn't involved. I get a video file and an audio file.

I think my issue is in my AppleScript, but I am out of my depths with it. What can I do to make my AppleScript run things just like they run in Terminal?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, please post your solution as an answer below instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What can I do to make my AppleScript run things just like they run in Terminal?

Well, you could `tell` the Terminal app to run your command:

```
tell application "Terminal" to do script "youtube-dl  " & input
```

But, I don't recommend this route, because it will actually open a Terminal window!

There are a whole host of differences between `do shell script` and typing commands into the Terminal. For starters, `do shell script` commands are run via `sh`, rather than the more advanced `bash` or `zsh` (And, your "#!/bin/zsh" shabang line at the top will have no effect in an Applescript!).

As to your actual problem, it sounds like youtube-dl can't find your copy of ffmpeg—probably because another difference between the Terminal app and `do shell script` is your PATH is set differently. Try specifying the location of your ffmpeg binary with youtube-dl's `--ffmpeg-location` flag.

If it helps to have a reference to look at, here is an Applescript I use to download videos from my web browser with youtube-dl. Note that I've been tweaking this for many years, so it has accumulated a lot of error checking, and code for compatibility with different browsers. Don't be intimidated! https://gist.github.com/Wowfunhappy/c2c8fc097a8b4f47430811fc1d0da041

Answer (score 3):

## `osascript`

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
on open location input
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl  " & quoted form of input
end open location
```

If run as a script, the hash-bang of your script should be the path to `osascript`. This is the process that runs AppleScript (an Open Scripting Architecture language) on macOS.

[Quote the URL](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/CallCommandLineUtilities.html) passed into `youtube-dl` to ensure it appears as a single argument to the tool.

Use the full path to `youtube-dl` to ensure the tool is found. Use `which youtube-dl` in Terminal to find the path.

### Command Line Arguments

If the AppleScript is being passed the URL as the first command line argument, [use the `argv` handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258142/how-can-i-open-applescript-app-with-arguments):

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
on run argv
   do shell shell script "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl " & quoted form of (item 1 of argv)
end run
```

If this is case, consider removing the script entirely and passing the argument directly to `youtube-dl`.

### Post Processing

`youtube-dl` has the ability to [post-process downloads](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#post-processing-options). You can control this using a [youtube-dl configuration file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237388/setup-youtube-dl-destination-to-downloads/237393#237393).

To specify the `ffmpeg` binary to be used add the following line to either a file at `/etc/youtube-dl.conf` or `~/.config/youtube-dl/config`:

```
--ffmpeg-location /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks an awful lot like a path problem - you have a script `youtube-dl` and the program `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` - in your AppleScript, try giving it the full path to your script.

Comment: Can you expand on what exactly I need to change, or where I can find the full path? I'm new to AppleScript. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: This is just a guess based on the info you've shared, but I believe if you change
`do shell script "youtube-dl  " & input` to `do shell script "~/youtube-dl  " & input` you should be good to go.

Note that "~/" means "in your home directory", so if your script is in another directory, replace "~/" with whatever that directory is.

Comment: For more info about the environment in AppleScript using "do shell script" stuff, check out [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG1-MY_COMMAND_WORKS_FINE_IN_TERMINAL__BUT_WHEN_I_TRY_TO_USE_IT_IN_DO_SHELL_SCRIPT__I_GET_AN_ERROR_ABOUT____COMMAND_NOT_FOUND______WHAT___S_GOING_ON_)